# I am Using opencart 1.5.5.1 It uses Jquery version 1.7 want to udate the jquery to the latest

Tags: jquery

I tried to use google jquery. The following script was used in in my opencart version 1.5.1.1 in header.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but its getting lots of errors. So instead of that i used

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please assist me how can i update opencart compatability to use latest version of jquery from Google API.

Thanks

Comment: What errors do you get? Please be more specific on your problem. Also, the scripts are both the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a lot of data from your question, and honestly updating an older version of something is dangerous without a deep review.

However, for a simple fix, you can TRY to use the jQuery Migrate plugin and a newer version of jQuery. This should keep the older needed functionality around.

Good luck.